# How to get document of WebView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, microsoft-edge

I'm using [Microsoft Toolkit Web View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) to embed **Microsoft Edge** in my **WPF C# application.**

I can't find anyway to get document and innerHTML of webview and there's nothing in documentation.

Here's XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="webviewtest.MainControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:webv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:webviewtest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Width="500" Height="500" >
    <Grid>
    <webv:WebView x:Name="webview_browser" Margin="0" IsJavaScriptEnabled="True" IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's C# :

```
public partial class MainControl : UserControl
    {

        public MainControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            webview_browser.Source = new Uri(@"http://google.com");
            
            ///// HOW TO GET webview_browser CONTENT AND HTML DOCUMENT 
           
        }
   
    }
```

I also tried :

```
string GETHTML = webview_browser.InvokeScript(@"document.innerHTML").ToString();
```

But I get this error :

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.' Exception:
> Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006
> (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as a method to your `MainControl` class

```
async private void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
    {
        string html = await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
        _html = html; //A property of your class to store the value when the event is fired
    }
```

And change this:

```
<webv:WebView x:Name="webview_browser" Margin="0" IsJavaScriptEnabled="True" IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True"/>
```

to this:

```
<webv:WebView x:Name="webview_browser" Margin="0" IsJavaScriptEnabled="True" IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True" DOMContentLoaded="WebView_DOMContentLoaded"/>
```

to fetch the html document after the page is loaded.

Comment: sorry , App goes frozen and not respond but if I use `document.getElementById('my_object').innerHTML;` it works , But I need to get full html of page.

Comment: Still freezing and it's `Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlDOMContentLoadedEventArgs`